# Creating Hyperlink to a Bookmark (OpenXML/Word)

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, openxml, bookmarks

Wow, I seem to be having an incredibly hard time finding examples of inserting a Hyperlink to a bookmark.

If I create a simple Word document with a link to a bookmark, the link looks something like this.

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00B61E6F" w:rsidRDefault="00E56782"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> HYPERLINK \l "Text" </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AC2FAA" w:rsidR="00AC2FAA">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Link</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

But what the heck is the instrText (FieldCode) value `HYPERLINK \l "Text"`? Is it described somewhere?

I tried implementing the above pattern as is. The result is it works but, in some cases, the text does not appear as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element instrText is documented in Part 1, section 17.16.23 of the Open XML standard, and the specific HYPERLINK codes are documented in 17.16.5.25. You can get a free copy of this standard as "ECMA-376 2nd edition" at [the Ecma 376 web page](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).

That doesn't exactly answer why your code doesn't work in some circumstances, though - are you perhaps pointing to a non-existent bookmark?

Comment: The links produced by my code do, in fact, *work*. They just don't take on the appearance of a link as the same code does in other documents. Thanks for the link. I'm downloading it now, although I seem to have got this working using the `Hyperlink` class.